# Problema con SUM en postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

estoy teniendo un problema: Con mi subconsulta SUM, quiero que se sumen por separado los costos de las consultas que se hicieran con la misma cedula que se tiene contratado el servicio, y se me estan sumando tooodas las consultas juntas.

````
SELECT p.*, total
FROM personas p, atenciones a, contratan c, (SELECT SUM(costo) FROM atenciones, contratan WHERE contratan.cedula=atenciones.cedula) as total
WHERE c.cedula=p.cedula and a.fecha between c.fecha_ini and c.fecha_fin and a.cedula=c.cedula ```
````

Comment: Puedes mostrar la estructura de las tablas, personas, atenciones y contratan?

Comment: Le falta en la subconsulta el predicado `and contratan.cedula = p.cedula`. El.problema no es el SUM. El problema es que debe fundamentarse más en consultas sobre modelos relacionales.

Answer (score 0):

Pensando en que la tabla persona tiene un id, y un nombre por ejemplo, podrías agrupar por estos campos y hacer el sum de costo que está en la tabla contratan.

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.nombre,
    SUM(c.costo) AS total
FROM 
    personas p JOIN 
    contratan c ON c.cedula = p.cedula JOIN 
    atenciones a ON a.cedula = c.cedula
    
WHERE 
    a.fecha BETWEEN c.fecha_ini AND c.fecha_fin 
GROUP BY p.id, p.nombre
```